# Custom nested class iterator for STL data structure

Tags: c++, class, oop, iterator, operators

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <list>

class City;
class MemberReport;

class CityReport
{
private:
    City* mCity;

protected:
    static const int BinSize = 7;

    class ReportsBin {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<MemberReport> mReports[BinSize+1];

        bool IsFull();
        void Add(std::shared_ptr<MemberReport> report);
    };

    std::list<std::shared_ptr<ReportsBin>> mReportBins;

public:
    explicit CityReport(City* city);

    void Add(std::shared_ptr<MemberReport> report);
    
    class Iter
    {
    public:
        Iter(CityReport *cityReport, int pos1, int pos2) : mCityReport(cityReport), mPos1(pos1), mPos2(pos2) {}

        bool operator!=(const Iter &other) const
        {
            return mPos1 != other.mPos1 || mPos2 != other.mPos2;
        }

        std::shared_ptr<MemberReport> operator *() const { return mCityReport->mReportBins[mPos1][mPos2]; }

        const Iter& operator++()
        {
            mPos1++;
            mPos2++;
            return *this;
        }
        
    private:
        CityReport *mCityReport;
        int mPos1;          
        int mPos2;         
    };

    Iter begin() { return Iter(this, 0, 0); }

    Iter end()   { return Iter(this, 0, 0); }
};
```

So I'm trying to create a custom iterator class for the class above however, I'm having trouble with the operator* and the operator++ due to the return type being stored in the form of a singly linked list inside of a list of shared pointers.

So I tried having the first parameter of the iterator constructor being `ReportsBin* reportsBin` although that didn't work since I need to return type `std::shared_ptr<MemberReport>` in the operator*. Now, I have it as `CityReport* cityReport` so that I can access the list of shared pointers `mReportBins` eventually leading to `mReports`. The problem is when I do mCityReport->mReportBins[mPos1][mPos2] to access `mReports`, I am not able to do so since you can't access lists using indices. My only other idea is to create an iterator within the operator* to iterate over the list of shared pointers of type `std::list<std::shared_ptr<ReportsBin>>` but I feel as though that defeats the whole purpose of the iterator class. I can't modify the CityReport class either, I can only work with the iterator class at hand.

Comment: `mReportBins[mPos1][mPos2]` doesn't work because `mReportBins[mPos1]` is not an array or something with an `operator[]`. In  fact neither is `mReportBins`.

Comment: why don't you change mPos1 to a list iterator instead of a number?

Comment: Why are you declaring the `mCity` as a pointer?

Comment: You need to support slightly more for the class to be considered an iterator. [See](https://cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/). You should probably also make sure that the `iterator_traits<CityReport:: Iter>` are set up correctly and for your type `CityReport` to be a proper container you need to support more than `bgin/end`

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think using `int` for `mPos1` is a mistake.
An iterator would be a better type in most situations. Unfortunately you make `mReportBins` accessible (as it is protected and not private) so depending on how you use it maybe `int` is better. **But** for argument’s sake; let's use an iterator.

While we are at it may as well use an iterator for `mPos2` as it will make the logic easier (though you can use `int` and swap checks for end against checks against the size of the array without any major difference.

Let's address the ReportsBin type first:

```
class ReportsBin {
public:
    // Rather than using a C-Array
    // Upgrade to a std::array this makes it easier using some types.
    using ReportsCont = std::array<std::shared_ptr<MemberReport>, BinSize+1>;

    // We may not be upgrading this to full container status.
    // But lets make accessing the members container here easier by
    // providing some simple iterator accesses to the memebers.
    using iterator  = ReportsCont::iterator;

    ReportsCont mReports;
    iterator    begin() {return std::begin(mReports);}
    iterator    end()   {return std::end(mReports);}

    bool IsFull();
    void Add(std::shared_ptr<MemberReport> report);
};
```

Next lets address the container you are using to store the `ReportBin`. You use a `std::list` and I am fine with theat. But lets make accessing the type information easier by using a couple of `using` directives.

```
using Container     = std::list<std::shared_ptr<ReportsBin>>;
using ContainerIter = Container::iterator;
Container   mReportBins;
```

Now we can define the member of `Iter` in terms of the types we have defined that makes it easy to read and easy to modify in a single place.

```
class Iter   // More traditionally this should be iterator
{
    // STUFF
    ..
    private:
        CityReport*             mCityReport;
        ContainerIter           mPos1;
        ReportsBin::iterator    mPos2;
};
```

This makes our dereference operator **trivial**.

```
    std::shared_ptr<MemberReport> operator*() const
    {
        return *mPos2;
    }
```

Constructor:

You only ever used the constructor to the first element. So why force this user to provide those 0,0. Let's remove that. Let's also not pass around raw pointers unless we really have to, so make the parameter a `CityReport&` so that users know it can never be `null` it always refers to something.

```
    Iter(CityReport& cityReport, ContainerIter p1)
        : mCityReport(&cityReport)                      // convert to pointer here
                                                        // Allows copying.
        , mPos1(p1)
    {
        // We can only set mPos2 if mPos1 is dereferancable.
        if (mPos1 != mCityReport->mReportBins.end()) {
            mPos2   = (*mPos1)->mReports.begin();
        }
    }
```

Like the constructor, you need to take special care of the test for situations where mPos1 is no longer dereference as mPos2 is no longer valid in a test. So the comparison becomes a little more complex:

```
    bool operator==(const Iter &other) const
    {
        auto end = mCityReport->mReportBins.end();
        // If mPos1 and other.mPos1 are both at the end.
        // then the value of mPos2 have no meaning, so don't compare.
        return (mPos1 == end && other.mPos1 == end)
            // Otherwise, make sure both iterators are the same.
            || (mPos1 == other.mPos1 && mPos2 == other.mPos2);
    }
    // Usually good to define both == and != and define them in
    // terms of each other for consistency.
    bool operator!=(const Iter &other) const    {return !(*this == other);}
```

This leaves the increment:

Your increment looks strange. If you want to move diagonally across the array that seems fine. But you don't make a check to make sure the two containers are square with each other. So it looks wrong. So I have taken the liberty of redefining the increment so it goes across all elements.

```
    const Iter& operator++()
    {
        // Increment mPos2 to the next element.
        // Note this is fine without a test.
        // It is illegal to call operator++ on an iterator where
        // mPos1 is at the end.
        ++mPos2;

        // If we reach the end of its container
        // Then we need to do some extra work to move to the next
        // container.
        if (mPos2 == (*mPos1)->mReports.end()) {
            // Increment the outer iterator.
            // If we are not at the end of the container
            // reset mPos2
            ++mPos1;
            if (mPos1 != mCityReport->mReportBins.end()) {
                mPos2   = (*mPos1)->mReports.begin();
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Now lets define begin and end.

```
Iter begin() { return Iter(*this, this->mReportBins.begin()); }
Iter end()   { return Iter(*this, this->mReportBins.end()); }
```

### Lets address other things you should be thinking about.

You look like you want to make this a container.
To do that you need to define a few more helper types in the container type and support a couple of other standard functions.

There are a couple of different types of container:

```
 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container
```

But the basics of what you "should" support are here:

```
 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container
```

Types your container should support:

```
// A typical container class will define these.
using value_type        = T;
using reference         = T&;   
using const_reference   = const T&; 
using iterator          = <Type of Your Iterator>;   
using const_iterator    = const iterator;
using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
using size_type         = std::size_t;
// Note: You may have to customize these.
//       Or explicitly not support them if that makes sense.
```

Your Iterator class should also define some (very similar types) types:

```
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits
```

You can define an explicit instantiation of `iterator_traits` to get these types. But it is usually easier to define them in the iterator type itself.

```
    using value_type        = MemberReport;
    using reference         = MemberReport&;
    using const_reference   = const MemberReport&;
    using iterator          = MemberReport*;
    using const_iterator    = MemberReport const*;
    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using size_type         = std::size_t;
```